# Can I display selected choices in calculation text field?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a Choice field using checkboxes type. I would like to have selected choices displayed in a separate field, which I have been trying to accomplish with a calculation field of text type.

For instance, in my screenshot, I would only want the first two selected choices to display for the end user.

[image: Field Settings - Choice]

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can do this with both a Text field, and a Calculation field. Just set the Default Value to be equal to your Choice fields title. In my example I have titled my Choice field 'Choice'.

[image]

This will show the following when viewing the form in preview or as an end user.

[image]

It is important to note that as you change your selections in the Choice feild the Calculation and Text field will both change as well.

For your specific case you will need to use the following calculation in the Default Value/Calculation field.

```
=TCFVAgreementItems
```

Comment: Can I separate the choices with a line break instead of a comma?